# "Unable to Display Current Owner" & Access Denied when trying to take ownership

Tags: windows-7, linux, permissions, file-permissions

I'm facing a problem where I (logged in as the Administrator) am unable to view file attributes.

Please see the screenshot below.

[image]
I'm not interested in taking ownership (even if I wanted to I'd to contend with the fact that"Access is Denied").
But if seeing the current owner can only be done by taking ownership its pretty pointless since the current owner would be me :) ?

What I want to see is who is the current owner.
I guess I could log in as the current owner (If its SYSTEM) & change permissions with SYSTEM ACCOUNT.

But how do I do this ?

**UPDATE**

**psexec -s cmd /c dir "E:\System Volume Information\" /a /q**

```
E:\System Volume Information>psexec -s cmd /c dir "E:\System Volume Information\" /a /q

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


 Volume in drive E is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is D8FC-3BF4

 Directory of E:\System Volume Information

08-10-2014  10:30    <DIR>          BUILTIN\Administrators .
08-10-2014  10:30    <DIR>          BUILTIN\Administrators ..
21-10-2014  09:30               136 BUILTIN\Administrators MountPointManagerRemoteDatabase
14-10-2014  11:21            20,480 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    tracking.log
22-09-2014  11:13    34,986,184,704 ...                    {060ece96-3720-11e4-bce5-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
19-06-2014  17:00            65,536 ...                    {3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
14-07-2014  15:17        91,275,264 ...                    {7204971e-0b1a-11e4-a348-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
14-07-2014  15:17           475,136 ...                    {72049720-0b1a-11e4-a348-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
23-07-2014  11:27     2,591,211,520 ...                    {720497be-0b1a-11e4-a348-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
25-09-2014  13:02         2,768,896 ...                    {720497c0-0b1a-11e4-a348-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
28-07-2014  10:35    24,944,459,776 ...                    {7204a0f0-0b1a-11e4-a348-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
22-10-2014  19:10    10,192,150,528 ...                    {7fb66a64-4e0a-11e4-b756-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
08-10-2014  00:11     3,145,728,000 ...                    {7fb66a66-4e0a-11e4-b756-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
14-07-2014  14:45     9,163,296,768 ...                    {a8789375-f60c-11e3-90a9-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
14-07-2014  14:45         1,589,248 ...                    {a8789376-f60c-11e3-90a9-005056c00008}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
              13 File(s) 85,119,225,992 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  182,760,902,656 bytes free
cmd exited on DHIWAKAR-PC with error code 0.
```

How do I see the owner where it shows ... ?

There is a folder name I've blacked out. Please don't mind that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered that if Administrators is the owner and there are multiple users with administrator privileges, ownership cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to assume the same rights as SYSTEM than I can think of no better tool to use than Psexec by Sysinternals. found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx  Psexec can allow you to run with higher priviledges than Admin by using the -s funtion. For instance: Psexec -s regedit will allow you to edit registry keys with SYSTEM level authority.  It can do all sorts of things to remote computers as well (or at least it used to until Microsoft put higher security on its machines). Just so you know, its a REAL bad idea running around your file system as SYSTEM (or Admin for that matter) malware or other beasties could gain the same rights as the current user and if that user is running as SYSTEM ...game over.  I have poor eyesight. whats the name of the files? I too am curious to know why you cant view the owner. at the very least it should say "trusted installer" (gets me suspicious)

Comment: Still doesn't work :( . See the update for my answer.

Comment: Well. theres always AccessEnum  by sysinternals and some other access checking tools in that suite. the owner might not be on the same domain and it wont list the owner. at most you might only get a sid.

Comment: Someone wrote a script to do exactly what you want: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/07/how-can-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-file.aspx  it cross references the sid with the sid class to get proper names.

Comment: Will try it & notify / update this comment with the result

Comment: Nope , Even with that Script I can't see the owner. At this point I'm pretty sure its owned by this user - nt authority\system S-1-5-18 . It happens to be a System File. What frustrates me is that I can't confirm this. Is there any indirect way of confirming ? Like getting the SID of the owner at least ?

Comment: You can actually use PsExec to get System access and grant full access to Administrators (without changing the owner). Then, as Admin, you can simply use the file explorer (right click > properties > security). I added a full answer with the commands.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution A: Powershell**

Open Powershell as Admin and run:

```
Get-Acl "path\to\file" | Format-List
```

Example command: `Get-Acl "E:\System Volume Information\{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}" | Format-List`

Example output:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::E:\System Volume Information\{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
Owner  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Group  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:SYG:SYD:P(A;;FA;;;SY)
```

**Solution B: PsExec (Sysinternals) + icacls**

Open cmd as Admin and run:

```
"path\to\your\SysinternalsSuite\folder\PsExec.exe" -s cmd
```

This opens a nested cmd instance with System access.
You can verify with `whoami`:

```
C:\_Sysinternals\SysinternalsSuite>PsExec.exe -s cmd

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2965]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>whoami
nt authority\system
```

Now that you have System access, grant full access to the "Administrators" user group:

```
icacls "path\to\file" /grant Administrators:(OI)(CI)F /T
exit
```

Now you can open the file explorer, navigate to the file or folder of choice, right click > Properties > Security tab and you'll see the owner.

**References / credits:**

- Thank you to [sloshnmosh](https://superuser.com/users/382808/sloshnmosh) for suggesting PsExec [here](https://superuser.com/a/831071/893789)!
- Credits to [Scripting Guy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-determine-the-owner-of-a-file/) for Powershell examples
- [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
- [icacls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)
- [icacls syntax example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311008/6096232)